# Black in my picturebox c#

Tags: c#, picturebox, highlight

when I use an image to a URL in my picture box I have black in here
Image = http://prntscr.com/cx1nre
I am known it's because my panel is on Highlight but when I use " Transparent " it give me a black in my picture box... example = http://prntscr.com/cwu9ev
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Are those url's the real ones you're using?

Comment: I can give you a URL for Exemple => http://futhead.cursecdn.com/static/img/17/players/196143.png

Comment: It works for me, just called Load and it displayed with no problem.

Comment: Can you screen please, for me it work http://prntscr.com/cx2d91 but if i use an another picturebox for make the card i have this => http://prntscr.com/cx2egx

Comment: Ok, I think your question is really misleading on what's happening to you, it's obvious your english is not very good (with no offense intention). Maybe what you're trying is to add a picturebox over other picturebox and when you make the top one transparent the transparent part becomes of the background color?

Comment: Maybe what you're trying is to add a picturebox over other picturebox and when you make the top one transparent the transparent part becomes of the background color? Yes, i'ts this

Comment: It works!  You see the back of your monitor.  *Something* is going to have to set the background, you cannot postpone it indefinitely.  If it is not the PictureBox because you set its BackColor to Transparent then it has to be its Parent, it cannot also be transparent.

Answer (score 2):

After understanding your question (one picture over other and the top with transparency), your problem is how .net transparency works, it's not real transparency, it copies the background of the container.

So, to make it work instead of two picture boxes add a panel and a picturebox inside the panel, set the backgroundimage of the panel to the image you wanted to use, and then set the overlay image on the picturebox. As .net copies the container's backgrond, as you added the picture box as a child of the panel the picture box will copy the image and the transparency would work as you expected.

Only caveat is that you need to load manually the image, but there are plenty of examples on how to load it.

Also, there's even a better approach: instead of two pictureboxes just add one, load into a Bitmap the background you want, retrieve a Graphics object from it, draw the second image with Graphics.DrawImage and then use the bitmap as the Image for the picturebox. It's more complicated but it's the most efficient way to do this.